# How to simulate out-of-storage on Android Simulator?

Tags: android, storage, simulation

## Background

I suspect that my code fails if a device runs low on storage.

## The challenge

How can I simulate a device with low (or no) storage left on the SD?

Comment: Have you tried limiting the size of the virtual SDCard, and then if required, filling it up. Right click settings, before running it. Unless i'm mistaken.

Comment: @Doomsknight I tried that, still looking for a quick way to fill up the remainings.